# Need help querying across two databases (first time trying to do this)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two databases I need to work with, db_site and db_forum (these are generic names, FYI).

db_site has a table called main-news, which has a **forumurl** field which holds a forum thread id and a **views** field which holds the current pageviews for the article entry in the database. db_forum has a table called forum_threads which has a **tid** field and a **replies** field.

I have two things I need to do, one using just the replies and another using the replies and the views. I assume once the former is figured out the latter won't be much more than adding some extra parts, so I'm concerned with the former for the time being.

Not sure how I should approach this since the two tables are in different databases. The login I'm using has access to both of them (AFAIK), so that isn't the problem, it's more of the syntax involved. Would what I'm looking to do be something like this, perhaps?

```
SELECT
    db_forum.forum_threads.replies AS replies
FROM
    `db_forum.forum_threads` AS f,
    `db_site.main-news` AS s
WHERE
    f.tid = s.forumurl
```

That's a rough guess, from what I can find online abut doing this type of query. Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: I changed "comments" to "replies" in the third paragraph, since I assume `db_forum.forum_threads.replies` is what you were referring to. Let me know if that's incorrect. Also edited the title to make it clear this is a cross-db query you're having trouble with. :)

Comment: You could have shortened the title to "Query across two databases".

Comment: @dja: Yeah, meant replies there. Also applied vog's title fix somewhat (querying instead of query) and fixed the code indentations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should indent your SQL code properly. That long line was almost unreadable.

```
SELECT
    db_forum.forum_threads.replies AS replies
FROM
    `db_forum.forum_threads` AS f,
    `db_site.main-news` AS s
WHERE
    f.tid = s.forumurl
```

Then, make use of your table aliases "f" and "s". You introduced them, so you have to use them:

```
SELECT
    f.replies AS replies
FROM
    `db_forum.forum_threads` AS f,
    `db_site.main-news` AS s
WHERE
    f.tid = s.forumurl
```

Finally, you should remove the unnecessary quoting:

```
SELECT
    f.replies AS replies
FROM
    db_forum.forum_threads AS f,
    db_site.main-news AS s
WHERE
    f.tid = s.forumurl
```

Comment: Sorry about the lack of indenting, in the PHP code I had open I had it on one line, and hadn't noticed the formatting issues it would have on SO. Wasn't for sure about the using the f. in the beginning, since I hadn't tried something like this before --- good to know it can work like that. I'll try this code out later tonight and check if it works (if it does I'll mark this as the answer).

Comment: These guidelines most frequently help illuminate the problems. When the script format is standardized many of the errors pop out. major plus.

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the fields are indicative of their function, then f.tid refers to an identity column while s.forumurl does not. Normally the s.formurl in this case would be a foreign key. Just a guess.